# UICollectionView Autosize cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have tableview cell collectionView inside each cell. In collectionView only images. There could be one or more 
If showing layout for 5 images it's ok. The issue when I am showing 1 image and need to resize collectionView according width and height of image. So I can show portrait images and landscape image. my current layout is

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        switch images.count {
        case 1:
            let size = collectionView.frame.size.width
            return CGSizeMake(size, 250)
        default:
            let size = collectionView.frame.size.width / 5
            let offset = CGFloat(5)
            return CGSizeMake(size - offset, size - offset)
        }
    }
```

I am using default CollectionViewFlowLayout
Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you explain what's the issue you are facing with above code?

Comment: The issue is with single photo inside collection view. I need resize collection view according photo content (including portrait or landscape photo orientation)

Answer (score 0):

I have added some work around below. Please check it out. Below codes are in Swift 3.0.

```
var collectionView:UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[collectionView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[collectionView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue:0), metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))

    //Register your cell to collectionView over here

}

//Add this method to support for orientation changes.
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: {(context) -> Void in

    }) {[weak self] (context) -> Void in

        self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Calling collectionView.performBatchUpdates will call the bellow method where you can able to adjust your cell size for orientation change

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    switch images.count {
    case 1:
        let size = collectionView.frame.size.width
        return CGSizeMake(size, 250)
    default:
        let size = collectionView.frame.size.width / 5
        let offset = CGFloat(5)
        return CGSizeMake(size - offset, size - offset)
    }
}
```

Also An ImageView which is on your CollectionViewCell should be pinned left and right margin of CollectionViewCell’s content view. And make sure that an image aspect ratio matched with the width of collectionView width or try to set the ImageView’s contentMode to scaleToFill.

Hope it helps!

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a question when rotating device. The question you have images in portrait and landscape mode. For example you shoot photo with device verticaly so your photo width will be less than height. I need only resize cell to its size to fit exacly size of image